# Automatic BIOS Update - No logs confirm legitimacy

Tags: malware, windows, windows-10, bios

As the title states. I rebooted my PC today and was greeted with a "BIOS is updating. Do not turn off or unplug from power."

I have an Asus Sabertooh Z170 mark 1. The only Asus utility I have is AI Suite 3 for fan control. No EZ-Update.

I have read that windows can push BIOS updates however I see nothing stating anything remotely to an Firmware update in the update history. In fact the last installed update was on the 14th of August..which was a cumulative & security update.

The 'new' updated firmware is 1703...which is from 2016.

The latest release as stated on the Asus website is 2018 April.

I have run 'Get-WindowsUpdateLog' in Powershell and searched that for any clues - Nothing.
This 'update' isn't recorded anywhere.

**How can I dig deeper to see what executed this install and where it came from?**

Comment: You appear to be confusing Windows updates with BIOS updates. Make sure you keep them separate in your investigations. To check on BIOS updates, you are going to have to look at ASUS tools and logs.

Comment: I mentioned Windows Updates due to the fact other uses have reported seeing "ASUSTek Computer Inc - Firmware" as a listed installed update after their forced auto BIOS update.

Again, I don't have any ASUS BIOS tools installed.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but when searching, don't assume that the Windows update logs will include the BIOS updates. They are different things.

Comment: Apologies, misunderstood your direction. Outside of the Windows Update logs I don't see anything else that could have recorded events? Not sure where else to look.

Comment: @schroeder Windows Update can deliver BIOS updates, so it's actually a sensible idea to check its history. I'm not sure if that kind of update would appear in the logs though.

Comment: Why not update to the latest UEFI firmware and not worry about it unless it fails?

Comment: @gronostaj yes, I understand that Asus uses Windows updates to deliver BIOS updates. But, I said what you said: that the BIOS update might not naturally show up in WU logs ...

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I guess to my paranoia. I have no idea what was done to my system and if it is malware to what extent its burrowed in..

Comment: @SheerKahn - It's not malware.  UEFI firmware updates are delivered through the Windows Update mechanism on certain classes of devices.  Additionally, malware cannot be delivered through Windows Update, multiple vectors would have to be compromised for that to be possible (so many it's an impossible amount).    UEFI updates delivered through Windows Update will be listed in the Windows Update history since they were delivered through Windows Update.  It seems you now know what the update actually was connected to (DBX) instead of a literally UEFI update itself.

Answer (score 1):

Further digging into each and every Windows Update found the following:

How it looks in Windows Update History:

2022-08 Security Update for Windows 10 [KB5012170](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5012170-security-update-for-secure-boot-dbx-august-9-2022-72ff5eed-25b4-47c7-be28-c42bd211bb15):

What it is:
Security Update for Secure Boot DBX

Windows devices that has Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) based firmware can run with Secure Boot enabled. The Secure Boot Forbidden Signature Database (DBX) prevents UEFI modules from loading. This update adds modules to the DBX.